# The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have a database with two tables. There is a primary key in both tables, AccountID which has a relationship.[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEfpy.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU9ox.png)[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbIXj.png)

[DonationsTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdisG.png) [HOAFeesTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0h4t.png)(All the entries on the HOAFees table are just test entries, the data entered aren't important)

I have a form that adds records to the HOAFees table. The code on the form is designed to find if an AccountID exists in the table already and if it does it edits the record. If the ID is not on the table already, it should add the record.
`

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub btnAddRecord_Click()
    'Declare variables
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim intID As Integer
    
    'Set the current database
    Set db = Application.CurrentDb
    
    'Set the recordset
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblHOAFees", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    'Set value for variable
    intID = lstAccountID.Value
    
    'Finds the Account ID selected on the form
    With rst
    rst.FindFirst "AccountID=" & intID
    
    'If the record has not yet been added to the form adds a new record
    If .NoMatch Then
            rst.AddNew
            rst!AccountID = intID
            rst!HOAID = txtHOAID.Value
            rst!Location = txtLocation.Value
            rst!House = chkHouse.Value
            rst!Rooms = txtRooms.Value
            rst!SquareFeet = txtSquareFeet.Value
            rst!HOAFees = txtHOAFees.Value
            rst.Update
    'If the Account ID is already in the form edits the record
    Else
            rst.Edit
            rst!AccountID = intID
            rst!HOAID = txtHOAID.Value
            rst!Location = txtLocation.Value
            rst!House = chkHouse.Value
            rst!Rooms = txtRooms.Value
            rst!SquareFeet = txtSquareFeet.Value
            rst!HOAFees = txtHOAFees.Value
            rst.Update
    End If
    End With
    

    'Closes the recordset
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    
End Sub
```

`

It works without any issues when editing an existing record. But when I add a new record and then try to close the form I get this: [ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hG61.png) The strange thing is though, when I click through all the errors and check the table. The new record is still added to the table despite it saying it can't save. How can I get this to stop coming up? Everything I keep finding is saying that an autonumber field is causing the error. But I don't have any auto number fields.

I've tried removing primary key from the HOAFees table, but it makes no difference. I need the primary key for the Donations table, so I can't change or have any duplicates on that.

Comment: the error message says "index, primary key or relationship" so it is not neccesarily the primary key that has duplicates - please show the structure of your table - your images show only the primary key

Comment: the root problem is you are misunderstanding how relationships work.  Until you understand let Access manage your primary keys.  create DonationID and HoaFeeID in the corresponding tables and set them to autonumber.  These will be each tables' PrimaryKey.  If AccountID and HOAID are coming from elsewhere keep them as regular columns.  add DonationFk to HoaFees and then hook up the DonationID to DonationFk.  then exit the relationship tool and select each table in turn and hit create form.  examine how the default forms work

Comment: This is for a school assignment, So I don't think I'm supposed to add Fields or change the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem with the error itself, and everything works fine, you just don't want the error message to appear, add code in the `OnError` event of the form, which checks if it's the error number you want to ignore.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Const ErrNumber = your_err_number
    If DataErr = ErrNumber Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    End If
End Sub
```